# How to place <h3> and <button> elements side to side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to figure out how to place my `<h4>` tag and `<button` tag to be side by side.

**Current Behaviour** - Right now they are underneath my image and I want them to put in a horizontal position.

**Required Behaviour** - I want the `<h4>` to be side by side with the image and the `<button>` side by side with the `<h4>`.

I tried floating to the right and display blocks, but the elements are still underneath the image and one another.

[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbjgRX)

Comment: Your codepen link is broken

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: sorry http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbjgRX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your codepan the real problem was that your button was outside the right div that is why it was not aligned next to `<h4>`. I have edited the code ([Updated Working Codepan](http://codepen.io/ManojSalvi/pen/zvgOwB))-

**Modified CODE**

```
<div class=" panel-body">
     <div class="row-fluid">
           <div class="row-fluid">
                <img class="hotel-img img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://en.hotel-palaciodelmar.com/static/galerias/hotel/01-hotel-santander-sercotel-palacio-del-mar-fachada-foto.jpg" />
                <h4 class="hotel-title""><span class="hotel-location"></span> Grand Master Flex</h4>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" href="#more-info" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> More info</button>
           </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

instead of this (your previous code) -

```
<div class=" panel-body">
     <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="row-fluid">
               <img class="hotel-img img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://en.hotel-palaciodelmar.com/static/galerias/hotel/01-hotel-santander-sercotel-palacio-del-mar-fachada-foto.jpg" />
               <h4 class="hotel-title""><span class="hotel-location"></span> Grand Master Flex</h4>
               </div>
           <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" href="#more-info" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> More info</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

and to align both `<h4>` and `<Button>` next to image you have to change your css and add `display: inline-block !important;` like this ([Updated Codepan with image alignment](http://codepen.io/ManojSalvi/pen/wKVwqN)) -

**CSS**

```
/* Hotel Search Panel */
.hotel-img {
  display: inline-block !important;
  width: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Browsers by default typically display header elements as `block`. Use `inline-block` to not have it be in it's own line.

HTML

```
<h4>title</h4>
<button>button</button>
```

CSS

```
h4 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**DEMO: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVPXOK**

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
<h4 style="display:inline-block;">
  heading
</h4>
<button> submit </button>
```

?

Comment: Thanks, but its for a class project and I am not allowed to use inline css

Answer (score 1):

Another option you can use is the "float-right" class. If you nest your button in the h4, it can be accomplished like so:

```
<h4>Title<button class="float-right">My Button</button></h4>
```

Hope that helps!